# How can I remove the feature that makes you whitelist blocks ( part of SUPEE-6788 )

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.14, whitelist

Where is the code located so I don't have to whitelist blocks? I hate this feature. I know it's security stuff but I don't want it on my local environment. Can someone please tell me how to remove it on the **Magento  1.14.2.4**.

Thanks

```
vagrant@precise32:/var/www/n98-magerun$ php n98-magerun.phar media:sync


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "media:sync" is not defined.                            
  Did you mean this?                                              
      media:dump
```

Comment: What magento version are you on?

Comment: @Rebel Magento ver. 1.14.2.4

Comment: Any updates @Rebel

Comment: Unfortunately, not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this, and just search for one of the many tools that can assist such as

https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons

> Find non-whitelisted vars/blocks to be compatible with SUPEE-6788 and Magento >1.9.2.2
>
> Thanks to @timvroom for the bulk of the code.
>
> dev:template-vars [--addblocks[="true|false"]] [--addvariables[="true|false"]]

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 worked fine but step 3 which is suppose to indicate if it's installed correct threw this error: -bash: n98-magerun.phar: command not found
@MartyS Magemojo Support

Comment: You still have to download or install the n98 tool itself for any module in n98-magerun to work.

Comment: Would that be this? https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

Comment: I got it installed but now i'm getting this error:  vagrant@precise32:/var/www/n98-magerun$ php n98-magerun.phar media:sync

                                                                  
  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "media:sync" is not defined.                            
  Did you mean this?                                              
      media:dump

Comment: I posted the error in my original post so it's easier to read. So close. Please help a bit more @MartyS Magemojo Support

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php` and change function `isTypeAllowed` to look like this:

   ```
   public function isTypeAllowed($type)
   {   
     #return Mage::helper('admin/block')->isTypeAllowed($type);
     return true;
   }
   ```
2. *Might be absolete but I will add it here anyway.* Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Helper/Block.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Admin/Helper/Block.php` and change function `isTypeAllowed` to look like this:

   ```
   public function isTypeAllowed($type)
   {               
     #return isset($this->_allowedTypes[$type]);
     return true;                                                                                                                                                 
   }
   ```

Comment: looks good; I'm checking it now. Thank you.

Comment: I'm still throwing errors in my log and my blocks aren't populating.2017-05-09T19:13:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Security problem: catalog/product_list has not been whitelisted.
2017-05-09T19:13:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): Security problem: me_quickview/popup has not been whitelisted.

Comment: Cleared cache as well. Nothing. =/

Comment: clear magento cache, opcache if you have one, restart server OR directly edit app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php

it is fully working here.

Comment: this call $this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type']) returns false in your case but it should return true. (_permissionBlock = Mage::getModel('admin/block'))

Comment: Will you please explain your last comment in more detail. @Konstantin

Comment: that is from the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php line 177. That is where 'has not been whitelisted' message comes from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58482/discussion-between-supplement-and-konstantin-gerasimov).